# Nothing was returned from render after React 17 update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, relayjs

I updated to React 17 and this test started failing:

```
  import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
  import { createMockEnvironment, MockPayloadGenerator } from 'relay-test-utils';

  describe('when loading is complete', () => {
    it('renders user fields', () => {
      jest.resetModules();

      const mockEnvironment = createMockEnvironment();

      jest.mock('../../../../environment', () => mockEnvironment);
      jest.mock('../User.react');

      const TakedownUserRenderer = require('../UserRenderer.react').default;
        
      const renderer = render(<UserRenderer id={1} />);

      expect(renderer.getByTestId('loading-user')).toBeTruthy();
      expect(renderer.queryByTestId('active-user')).toBeFalsy();

        // Fails here
      mockEnvironment.mock.resolveMostRecentOperation(operation =>
        MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation),
      );
    });
  });
```

The component:

```
class UserRenderer extends PureComponent<Props> {
    render(): Node {
        return (
            <QueryRenderer
                variables={{ id: props.id}}
                query={UserRendererQuery}
                environment={environment}
                render={({ props }) => {
                    return (
                        <div data-testid="takedown-user">
                            <TakedownUser user={props?.node} />
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default UserRenderer;
```

Error:

Failed: "Error: ForwardRef(Relay(User))(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

```
  30 |       expect(renderer.queryByTestId('active-user')).toBeFalsy();
  31 | 
> 32 |       mockEnvironment.mock.resolveMostRecentOperation(operation =>
     |                            ^
  33 |         MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation),
  34 |       );
  35 |     });
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix?